# Re-apply PR due to exit Singapore with expired re-entrance permit

Tags: resident-permit, pr, singapore

I have permanent residency in Singapore.

Yesterday, I had to go overseas to visit my family. At airport immigration, the official told me my re-entrance permit expired two weeks ago. The official said that f I leave, my PR will be canceled immediately. However, I can re-apply for PR again soon after I return to Singapore. Due to urgent family matters, I didn't think carefully and left Singapore.

After I arrived and re-united with my family, I thought about everything that is affected if I don't have my PR: my job, my HDB, bank loan, my insurance...

Is it easy to get approval to get my PR back? Usually how long will it take? During this period before approval, can I continue my work, or will I have to stop my job?

I have stayed and worked in Singapore for about 15 years. All the while my husband applied for me and my daughter's PR and re-entrance permits. Until yesterday, it is the first time I heard and knew that PR need a re-entrance permit. It even shocked me that he renewed himself and our daughter re- entrance permits but did not do mine.

Comment: According to https://www.ica.gov.sg/PR/reentry/pr_reentry_apply if you leave Singapore or remain overseas without a valid REP, you lose your permanent residence.

Comment: What am facing similar situation right now. Can you share your experience with me. Do you managed to get your PR status back and how

Comment: See https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/273/reinstatement-of-singapore-permanent-residency

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reinstatement of Singapore permanent residency](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/273/reinstatement-of-singapore-permanent-residency)