# 2nd Gen Ex-PR trying to get back to Singapore

Tags: singapore, work-permit

I have formally left Singapore due to family pressure as my sibling has Autism and his treatment wasn't going well in Singapore , hence came back to India. I have not completed NS as I was 12 when I left Singapore formally. Is there a chance where I can have my PR back if I request Singapore gov to reinstate PR ? I do have good technical knoweldge and am sure that I can get a job there. All other post I read said that there is chance of getting Employement Pass but no way I would get PR in anyway possible. Would like to understand if that would be same in my situation as I have left Singapore before even getting formal notice from Singapore for NS. [ Note : We have received an opportunity to get Singaporean green card or Singapore residency and declined it as well. ( At least my parents did ).

I strongly want to come back to Singapore , but it seems that its very hard. Some post also said that if were ex-pr even getting EP is impossible. But feel like there might be chance as my skills are in demand in Singapore.

I left at 2009. My age was 13 years old

Note: I have lived in Singapore since I was kid , completed entire education from nursery till PSLE (P6).

Comment: How long ago did you leave Singapore?

Comment: I left at 2009. My age was 13 years old.

Comment: Please edit that into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This question has remained unanswered for months, suggesting that the information sought is not readily available.

You could contact the [Singapore Law Society](https://www.lawsociety.org.sg), and ask them how to find a Singapore lawyer who works in the field of immigration law.

Answer (score 1):

If you left Singapore as a second generation PR without completing your National Service, it is *extremely* unlikely that your PR would be reinstated.  Quite the contrary, if your parents did not do the proper paperwork, you may well be arrested on arrival as a deserter and sent directly to boot camp.

I would suggest you contact CPMB to verify your National Service status.  If you are liable for NS, you could consider returning to Singapore to serve your two years, after which your PR *may* be reinstated.  If you are not liable, you could potentially return to Singapore to study/work on an EP.  But there is highly unlikely to be any path that would see you return to Singapore as a PR without completing your NS.

See also: [Reinstatement of Singapore permanent residency](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/273/reinstatement-of-singapore-permanent-residency)